Converting part of a multiqc_data JSON to TSV with jq
I'm trying to convert a multiqc_data.json file to a tsv file. Specifically, I only need part of data from "report_general_stats_data" section. The structure is:
{
       "report_general_stats_data": [
        {
            "contigs": {
                "# contigs (>= 0 bp)": 232.0,
                "# contigs (>= 1000 bp)": 169.0,
                "# contigs (>= 5000 bp)": 121.0,
                "# contigs (>= 10000 bp)": 107.0,
                "# contigs (>= 25000 bp)": 75.0,
                "# contigs (>= 50000 bp)": 37.0,
                "Total length (>= 0 bp)": 5594769.0,
                "Total length (>= 1000 bp)": 5569601.0,
                "Total length (>= 5000 bp)": 5452934.0,
                "Total length (>= 10000 bp)": 5349401.0,
                "Total length (>= 25000 bp)": 4801158.0,
                "Total length (>= 50000 bp)": 3427439.0,
                "# contigs": 187.0,
                "Largest contig": 216595.0,
                "Total length": 5582595.0,
                "Reference length": 5472672.0,
                "GC (%)": 57.1,
                "Reference GC (%)": 57.37,
                "N50": 63236.0,
                "NG50": 64616.0,
                "N90": 19080.0,
                "NG90": 21621.0,
                "auN": 81138.9,
                "auNG": 82768.6,
                "L50": 26.0,
                "LG50": 25.0,
                "L90": 86.0,
                "LG90": 81.0,
                "# N's per 100 kbp": 0.0
            }
        },
        {
            "24-240_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1106872.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 32142.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.10114,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1106872.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 296659710.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 268093576.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 233354655.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.903707,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.786607,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 268.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 267.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.565903,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1139014.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.1780856073762,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 60616.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 1262446.0,
                "pct_adapter": 5.321795869058677
            },
            "24-278_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 2161572.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 50870.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.20167800000000002,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 2161572.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 529325786.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 491653949.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 442959345.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.928831,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.836837,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 244.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 244.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.560734,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 2212442.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.70073068582137,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 187672.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 4596580.0,
                "pct_adapter": 8.48257265049208
            },
            "24-288_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1531162.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 51164.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.11451499999999999,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1531162.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 409223893.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 375027676.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 333000899.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.916436,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.813738,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 267.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 267.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.562734,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1582326.0,
                "pct_surviving": 96.76653230750173,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 97506.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 2027444.0,
                "pct_adapter": 6.162194136985678
            },
            "24-275_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1673478.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 40514.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.10735199999999999,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1673478.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 439326257.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 401596781.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 354025417.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.91412,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.805837,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 262.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 262.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.560707,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1713992.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.6362783490238,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 149906.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 3353406.0,
                "pct_adapter": 8.746015150595802
            },
            "24-269_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 2302934.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 51540.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.194948,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 2302934.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 560492864.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 521238294.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 469860972.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.929964,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.8383,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 243.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 243.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.565888,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 2354474.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.81097603965895,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 203026.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 5012952.0,
                "pct_adapter": 8.622987554757454
            },
            "24-276_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1417706.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 57658.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.12457900000000001,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1417706.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 357804610.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 328089731.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 292560788.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.916952,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.817655,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 252.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 252.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.559441,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1475364.0,
                "pct_surviving": 96.0919474787239,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 133228.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 3293571.0,
                "pct_adapter": 9.03017831531744
            },
            "24-246_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 666866.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 12134.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.0768778,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 666866.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 176201195.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 158672752.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 136656453.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.90052,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.775571,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 264.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 263.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.560996,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 679000.0,
                "pct_surviving": 98.21296023564065,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 41992.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 873172.0,
                "pct_adapter": 6.18438880706922
            },
            "24-287_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1761992.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 57788.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.140786,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1761992.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 452625879.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 414709658.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 368660242.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.916231,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.814492,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 256.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 256.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.562427,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1819780.0,
                "pct_surviving": 96.82445130730089,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 143030.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 3336030.0,
                "pct_adapter": 7.859741287408369
            },
            "24-270_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 2304254.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 60436.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.145389,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 2304254.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 595769254.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 548648672.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 489253928.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.920908,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.821214,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 258.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 258.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.561259,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 2364690.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.44423159061019,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 186984.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 4124802.0,
                "pct_adapter": 7.907336691067328
            },
            "24-279_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1851444.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 55646.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.158147,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1851444.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 467943785.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 432758485.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 388427451.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.924809,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.830073,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 252.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 252.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.564391,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1907090.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.08215134052405,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 146844.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 3434243.0,
                "pct_adapter": 7.699898798693297
            },
            "24-295_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1532672.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 58592.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.127194,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1532672.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 409691227.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 374266368.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 331209675.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.913533,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.808437,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 267.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 267.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.56121,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1591264.0,
                "pct_surviving": 96.31789571057978,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 90732.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 1903577.0,
                "pct_adapter": 5.701882277233696
            },
            "24-277_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1498306.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 33490.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.1132,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1498306.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 389095200.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 355870530.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 314058539.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.91461,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.807151,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 259.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 259.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.562061,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1531796.0,
                "pct_surviving": 97.8136775393068,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 106956.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 2318318.0,
                "pct_adapter": 6.982391911194441
            },
            "24-274_L001_R1_001": {
                "filtering_result_passed_filter_reads": 1710930.0,
                "filtering_result_low_quality_reads": 73040.0,
                "filtering_result_too_many_N_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_short_reads": 0.0,
                "filtering_result_too_long_reads": 0.0,
                "pct_duplication": 0.116482,
                "after_filtering_total_reads": 1710930.0,
                "after_filtering_total_bases": 449663434.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_bases": 407856941.0,
                "after_filtering_q30_bases": 359065093.0,
                "after_filtering_q20_rate": 0.907027,
                "after_filtering_q30_rate": 0.79852,
                "after_filtering_read1_mean_length": 262.0,
                "after_filtering_read2_mean_length": 262.0,
                "after_filtering_gc_content": 0.562058,
                "before_filtering_total_reads": 1783970.0,
                "pct_surviving": 95.90576074709777,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads": 144878.0,
                "adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases": 3253300.0,
                "pct_adapter": 8.12110069115512
            }
        },
        {
            "R1.cor": {
                "s_name": "R1.cor",
                "totalpairs": 855465,
                "discardpairs": 0,
                "percdiscard": 0,
                "combopairs": 796467,
                "inniepairs": 0,
                "outiepairs": 0,
                "uncombopairs": 58998,
                "perccombo": 93.1
            }
        }
    ],
    "config_creation_date": "2024-11-28, 17:31 UTC",
    "config_git_hash": null,
    "config_intro_text": null,
    "config_report_comment": null,
    "config_report_header_info": null,
    "config_script_path": "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/multiqc",
    "config_short_version": "1.23",
    "config_subtitle": null,
    "config_title": null,
    "config_version": "1.23",
    "config_output_dir": "/home/ubuntu"
}

I am looking to use jq to extract certain fields from "report_general_stats_data" section. My expected output would look something like:
"Sample"\t"filtering_result_passed_filter_reads"\t"filtering_result_low_quality_reads"...\t"pct_adapter"
"24-240_L001_R1_001"\t"1106872.0"\t"32142.0"...\t"5.321795869058677"

and so on the rest of samples.
So far I have written following script with no success:
jq -r '.report_general_stats_data[1] | @tsv' multiqc_data.json > multiqc_data.tsv

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Alberto

This sample JSON has duplicate keys ("24-277_L001_R1_001"), object-final commas (0.562058,}), and keys outside of objects (} "before_filtering_total_reads": 1783970.0). Please correct them first.

As for your attempt, @tsv requires an array of strings (or stringifiable items). With .report_general_stats_data[1], you just provide an object. The part to destructure it is missing in between. You need to collect the items you want to be printed into an array, e.g. map(.filtering_result_passed_filter_reads, .filtering_result_low_quality_reads, …)

Corrected duplicate keys and keys outside of objects. Many thanks!

Here's an attempt at solving the problem; the idea is to first get the unique keys from all the samples and use them to extract the data of each sample in the same order. Also, there's an additional "trick" which is to prepend the sample name to the sample data object:
.report_general_stats_data[1]
| to_entries
| map({"Sample": .key} * .value)
| ([.[] | keys_unsorted[]] | unique) as $head
| ($head, (.[] | . as $cols | $head | map($cols[.])))
| @tsv

Sample              adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_bases  adapter_cutting_adapter_trimmed_reads  after_filtering_gc_content  after_filtering_q20_bases  after_filtering_q20_rate  after_filtering_q30_bases  after_filtering_q30_rate  after_filtering_read1_mean_length  after_filtering_read2_mean_length  after_filtering_total_bases  after_filtering_total_reads  before_filtering_total_reads  filtering_result_low_quality_reads  filtering_result_passed_filter_reads  filtering_result_too_long_reads  filtering_result_too_many_N_reads  filtering_result_too_short_reads  pct_adapter        pct_duplication      pct_surviving
24-240_L001_R1_001  1262446.0                              60616.0                                0.565903                    268093576.0                0.903707                  233354655.0                0.786607                  268.0                              267.0                              296659710.0                  1106872.0                    1139014.0                     32142.0                             1106872.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               5.321795869058677  0.10114              97.1780856073762
24-278_L001_R1_001  4596580.0                              187672.0                               0.560734                    491653949.0                0.928831                  442959345.0                0.836837                  244.0                              244.0                              529325786.0                  2161572.0                    2212442.0                     50870.0                             2161572.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               8.48257265049208   0.20167800000000002  97.70073068582137
24-288_L001_R1_001  2027444.0                              97506.0                                0.562734                    375027676.0                0.916436                  333000899.0                0.813738                  267.0                              267.0                              409223893.0                  1531162.0                    1582326.0                     51164.0                             1531162.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               6.162194136985678  0.11451499999999999  96.76653230750173
24-275_L001_R1_001  3353406.0                              149906.0                               0.560707                    401596781.0                0.91412                   354025417.0                0.805837                  262.0                              262.0                              439326257.0                  1673478.0                    1713992.0                     40514.0                             1673478.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               8.746015150595802  0.10735199999999999  97.6362783490238
24-269_L001_R1_001  5012952.0                              203026.0                               0.565888                    521238294.0                0.929964                  469860972.0                0.8383                    243.0                              243.0                              560492864.0                  2302934.0                    2354474.0                     51540.0                             2302934.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               8.622987554757454  0.194948             97.81097603965895
24-276_L001_R1_001  3293571.0                              133228.0                               0.559441                    328089731.0                0.916952                  292560788.0                0.817655                  252.0                              252.0                              357804610.0                  1417706.0                    1475364.0                     57658.0                             1417706.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               9.03017831531744   0.12457900000000001  96.0919474787239
24-246_L001_R1_001  873172.0                               41992.0                                0.560996                    158672752.0                0.90052                   136656453.0                0.775571                  264.0                              263.0                              176201195.0                  666866.0                     679000.0                      12134.0                             666866.0                              0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               6.18438880706922   0.0768778            98.21296023564065
24-287_L001_R1_001  3336030.0                              143030.0                               0.562427                    414709658.0                0.916231                  368660242.0                0.814492                  256.0                              256.0                              452625879.0                  1761992.0                    1819780.0                     57788.0                             1761992.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               7.859741287408369  0.140786             96.82445130730089
24-270_L001_R1_001  4124802.0                              186984.0                               0.561259                    548648672.0                0.920908                  489253928.0                0.821214                  258.0                              258.0                              595769254.0                  2304254.0                    2364690.0                     60436.0                             2304254.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               7.907336691067328  0.145389             97.44423159061019
24-279_L001_R1_001  3434243.0                              146844.0                               0.564391                    432758485.0                0.924809                  388427451.0                0.830073                  252.0                              252.0                              467943785.0                  1851444.0                    1907090.0                     55646.0                             1851444.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               7.699898798693297  0.158147             97.08215134052405
24-295_L001_R1_001  1903577.0                              90732.0                                0.56121                     374266368.0                0.913533                  331209675.0                0.808437                  267.0                              267.0                              409691227.0                  1532672.0                    1591264.0                     58592.0                             1532672.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               5.701882277233696  0.127194             96.31789571057978
24-277_L001_R1_001  2318318.0                              106956.0                               0.562061                    355870530.0                0.91461                   314058539.0                0.807151                  259.0                              259.0                              389095200.0                  1498306.0                    1531796.0                     33490.0                             1498306.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               6.982391911194441  0.1132               97.8136775393068
24-274_L001_R1_001  3253300.0                              144878.0                               0.562058                    407856941.0                0.907027                  359065093.0                0.79852                   262.0                              262.0                              449663434.0                  1710930.0                    1783970.0                     73040.0                             1710930.0                             0.0                              0.0                                0.0                               8.12110069115512   0.116482             95.90576074709777

